# Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function while clicking on submit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, dispatch

After entering the text in input field and clicking submit button the error occurs: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function boundActionCreators.<computed> [as setAlert]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert.js';  
const Register = (props) => { 
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({name: '',email: '',password: '',password2: ''}); 
const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData; 
const onChange = (e) => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
    props.setAlert('password does not match', 'danger');
    } else {
    console.log('Success');
    }
};

return (
    <section className='container'>
        <form className='form' onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <input type='email' name='email' value={email} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />             
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <input type='password' name='password' value={password} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}/>
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <input type='password' name='password2' value={password2} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}/>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' value='Register' />
        </form>
    </section>
)};
export default connect(null, { setAlert })(Register);

//action 
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'; 
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types.js';

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType) => (dispatch) => { 
    const id = uuid; 
    dispatch({ 
        type: SET_ALERT, 
        payload: { msg, alertType, id }, 
    }); 
};

//reducer 
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from '../actions/types.js';

const InitialState = [];

export default function(state = InitialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action; 
    switch (type) { 
       case SET_ALERT: 
           return [...state, payload]; 
       case REMOVE_ALERT: 
           return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== payload); 
       default: 
           return state; 
    } 
}
```

I have also tried by using useDispatch fn and try to warp setAlert call in dispatch in onsubmit, but didn' work.

what could be the issue?

Comment: are you using useEffect to handle the rendering property properly

Comment: Let us see you useDispatch code as well then we can conclude on it.

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena Thanks for looking into this.
This issue is resolved. It was due to some issue in Store code.